# Using both treatment and sum coding in a single model?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interaction

I am running a regression with two independent variables. The dependent variable is accuracy.

I am looking to see if being at Level 1 of Factor A makes you more likely to be correct than being at Level 2 of Factor A. So I will code Level 1 '1' and Level 2 '0'.

But now I am curious if this interacts with Factor B. Would it make sense to use sum coding for Factor B (i.e., coding Level 1 '-.5' and Level 2 '.5'.), as I am not interested if either Level 1 or Level 2 of Factor B leads to more accurate responses?

Comment: I suppose you could do it, but I'm not sure what the advantage is. You are only changing the presentation of the output, not anything substantive. A more important question is what this "accuracy" is. Do you have a number of 'trials' of some sort that were 'successful' or not?

Comment: I'm analyzing it at the trial level, using a mixed effects logistic regression.

I guess my reasoning for using sum coding was that I have no reason to expect one level of Factor B to lead to higher accuracy, so I wouldn't know which to code as 1 and which as 0?

Comment: OK, the GLMM seems appropriate. Which becomes the reference level will just flip the sign on the coefficient. There's nothing really to worry about there.

Comment: Ah okay!

Will it not change the interpretation of the interaction?

Answer (score 1):

*(Turning comments into an answer.)*

I suppose you could do it, but I'm not sure what the advantage is. You are only changing the presentation of the output, not anything substantive.  Which becomes the reference level will just flip the sign on the coefficient. There's nothing really to worry about there.  Similarly, it can affect the sign on the interaction term in your output, but should have no effect the substance. Usually, you just use the interaction to test for significance. It is best not to try to interpret the interaction directly, but to look at the *simple effects* (i.e., 'when B=0, accuracy increases with A, but when B=1, accuracy decreases with A').

Comment: Strange, I compared coding Level 1/2 as 1/0 and 0/1 and got very different results.

Comment: Can you paste your output into your Q? There shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: Could I send you the results in an email?

My address is dsidhu@ucalgary.ca If you send me an email I will reply with the results.

Comment: Just paste your `summary(model)` output into your question, @David. That should be enough.